# Rails inject link in html component

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, draper

Using Rails 4.2 and Draper gem.
I have a decorator:

```
  def status_link
    if enabled?
      h.link_to 'Disable', h.disable_company_path(id), data: {confirm: 'Are you sure?'}, method: :put, remote: true
    else
      h.link_to 'Enable', h.enable_company_path(id), method: :put, remote: true
    end
  end
```

I want to render the link in js view:

```
var cell = $("#my-id");
cell.html(<%= @my_model.decorate.status_link %>);
```

But the link is not injected in the cell. The cell is empty.

If I print in console the `status_link` method it works:

```
<%= pp  @my_model.decorate.status_link %>
"<a data-confirm=\"Are you sure?\" data-remote=\"true\" rel=\"nofollow\" data-method=\"put\" href=\"/companies/210/disable\">Disable</a>"
```

If I try to inject an integer it works:

```
cell.html(<%= @my_model.id %>);
```

Also I have try to use double quote:

```
cell.html("<%= @my_model.decorate.status_link %>");
```

But the result is the same. I have try to inspect the code with the browser console but no errors are shown

Why the link is not injected while integer works fine?

Comment: Check your browser console, you'll be seeing a JS error. Also inspect response of that ajax call. It contains invalid javascript.

Comment: Hint: you need quotes.

Comment: Just tryied.. with double quotes don't work also

Comment: Try single quotes then.

Comment: Did you also try the "inspect response" part?

Comment: with single quotes is working well. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The following is invalid:

```
cell.html(<%= @my_model.decorate.status_link %>);
```

You need to call the javascript function with a string, i.e.:

```
cell.html("<%= @my_model.decorate.status_link %>");
```

The takeaway point here should not be memorising this specific error, but rather, learning how to debug your code.

Navigate to the relevant page in your application and open the browser console. Now perform whatever action should trigger that javascript - such as a page refresh, or clicking a button. You should see an error in the log; something like this:

[image: Console error]

This also includes a link to the line of code that the error originated from - i.e. in your case, the `cell.html(<%=....` code.

Comment: I have try to inspect: no errors. I also have used double quoted but the the result is the same